# Python: file attachment not working while sending email by crontab

Tags: python, unix, cron

The following source code is working fine when running manually but with crontab job mail is successfully sending but files are not attached.How can I fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib
import os
import datetime
import glob
import time
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

now = datetime.datetime.now()
fi = now.strftime("%d%m%Y" '_0600_final.txt')
files1=glob.glob('*%s'%fi)
time.sleep(20)
print(files1)
me = 'abc@abc.com'
you = ['abc@abc.com']  
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "abc Report"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = ", ".join(you)
text = "Hi!\n\nPlease find attached today's Counter files.\n\nRegards,\nabc"
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
msg.attach(part1)

for f in files1:  
    file_path = os.path.join('/tmp/', f)
    print(file_path)
    attachment = MIMEApplication(open(file_path, "rb").read(), _subtype="txt")
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment', filename=f)
    msg.attach(attachment)
s = smtplib.SMTP('10.0.0.1')
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Here is crontab job entry:

```
0 9 * * * python /tmp/send_mail_2.py
```

Comment: Can you please try using absolute paths for attachments?

Comment: Yes, I am using the full path also script is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is related to the folder where the attachment are located.

Keep in mind that if you run your script from crontab your python execution will probably be in a different folder than the one you're executing it manually from.

Therefore I suggest two possible solutions:

- Use absolute paths for your attachments
- Move Python path into your script path as soon as the script starts

You can achieve the 2nd result with a similar snippet:

```
import os

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)
```

If you want to troubleshoot and better understand what is going on you could simply run the current version of your script using crontab and save its current working directory in a file using something similar:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write(os.getcwd())
```

Edit:
The issue was solved using the 2nd option suggested: *Move Python path into your script path as soon your script starts*.

Comment: Many thanks, it is working for me with the second option.