# Error when scheduling python script: fcron[12036]: Couldn't exec '/usr/bin/sendmail': No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron, smtplib

I have a python script that I would like to schedule with fcrontab. This script sends emails based on the status field set in one of the columns. The script executes in the expected manner when I invoke the following:

```
python2 mail.py
```

This results in the following and expected output:

```
Successfully sent email... 
Update sent status on EdPost...  xxxxxx
Update sent status on EdPost...  xxxxxx
Update sent status on EdPost...  xxxxxx
Update sent status on EdPost...  xxxxxx
Update sent status on EdPost...  xxxxxx
Update sent status on EdPost...  xxxxxx
Update sent status on EdPost...  xxxxxx
Update sent status on EdPost...  xxxxxx
```

However when I try to run this script as a cron job, I end up with the mentioned error.

Cron:

```
0 15 * * * /home/x/JobParse/mail.py >> /home/x/JobParse/mailer.log
```

Error:

```
fcron[23191]: Couldn't exec '/usr/bin/sendmail': No such file or directory
```

I have another python script scheduled in a similar fashion that runs just fine with the `#!/usr/bin/env python2` shebang. That script does not use the smtplib library though.

The script I'm trying to schedule is below:

mail.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python2
import smtplib
from db import get_records,update_sent_status
import traceback
import datetime
configs = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('configs')]
usr = configs[0]
pwd = configs[1]
rcvr = configs[2]
receivers = [rcvr]
date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
posts = []
edpost_tbl_rows= ""
appli_tbl_rows= ""

ed_posts = get_records(0) # * non-appli and  unsent
ed_posts_ids = [row[0] for row in ed_posts]
ed_posts_sent = get_records(1) # post_id

uniq_appli = get_records(2) # unique unsent appli
uniq_appli_ids = [row[0] for row in uniq_appli]

all_appli_sent = [row[0] for row in get_records(4)] # all app_id sent
all_appli_unsent = [row[0] for row in get_records(5)] # all app_id unsent


# No jobs to send so exit
if len(all_appli_unsent) == 0 and len(ed_posts) == 0:
    print "Exit: No new unique posts.."
    exit()

# Transform db data into html table row format
for row in ed_posts:
    edpost_tbl_rows += \
            "<tr style=\"border:1px solid black\"><td style=\"border:1px solid black\">"\
            +str(row[0])\
            +"</td><td style=\"border:1px solid black\"><a href="\
            +'"'\
            +row[1]\
            +'"'\
            +">"\
            +row[4]\
            +"</a></td><td style=\"border:1px solid black\">"\
            +row[5]\
            +"</td><td style=\"border:1px solid black\">"\
            +row[6]\
            +"</td></tr>"

# Transform applitrack posts into html table
for row in uniq_appli:
    # check if sent before - app_id not unique on edpost
    if row[3] not in all_appli_sent:
        print "New unique & unsent applitrack post... ",row[3]
        appli_tbl_rows += \
            "<tr style=\"border:1px solid black\"><td style=\"border:1px solid black\">"\
            +str(row[0])\
            +"</td><td style=\"border:1px solid black\"><a href="\
            +'"'\
            +row[2]\
            +'"'\
            +">"\
            +str(row[3])\
            +"</a></td><td style=\"border:1px solid black\"><a href="\
            +'"'\
            +row[1]\
            +'"'\
            +">"\
            +row[4]\
            +"</a></td><td style=\"border:1px solid black\">"\
            +row[5]\
            +"</td><td style=\"border:1px solid black\">"\
            +row[6]\
            +"</td></tr>"
    else:
        print "Skipping applitrack post... ",row[3]


message = """From: JobUpdates <{usr}>
To: xxxx <{rcvr}>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Subject: New Job Postings: {date}

<p>Check out these postings you may have not have seen yet :)</p>
<p>Searched: words

<h2>Jobs With Applitrack</h2>
<table style="width:100%;border:1px solid black">
    <tr style="border:1px solid black">
        <th style="border:1px solid black">EdPost ID</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black">AppliTrack ID</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black">Description</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black">Post DT</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black">Exp DT</th>
    </tr>
    {appli_tbl_rows}
</table>
</br>
</br>
<h2>Jobs Without Applitrack</h2>
<table style="width:100%;border:1px solid black">
    <tr style="border:1px solid black">
        <th style="border:1px solid black">EdPost ID</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black">Description</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black">Post DT</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black">Exp DT</th>
    </tr>
    {edpost_tbl_rows}
</table>
""".format(usr=usr,rcvr=rcvr,date=date,edpost_tbl_rows=edpost_tbl_rows,appli_tbl_rows=appli_tbl_rows)

try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost',1025)
    smtpObj.login(usr,pwd)
    smtpObj.sendmail(usr, rcvr, message)
    print "Successfully sent email... "
    for post_id in ed_posts_ids:
        print "Update sent status on EdPost... ",post_id
        update_sent_status(post_id)

    for app_id in all_appli_unsent:
        print "Update sent status on Appli... ",app_id
        update_sent_status(app_id,1)

except smtplib.SMTPException:
    print "ERROR: unable to send email... "
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

I've tried this with the `#!/usr/bin/env python2` shebang as well to no avail.

Comment: it looks like cron problem, not Python code problem. Usually cron sends mail to user when there is problem with running script. It seems it try to send mail but it can't find sendmail for it. First you should check if you can run `/usr/bin/sendmail` in terminal.

Comment: I do not have sendmail installed. I hadn't realized that cron might need it. I'll work on installing and configuring it, and hopefully it will give me more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue without installing sendmail. This was done by moving the Python path into the script at the start of it as follows:

```py
import os
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)
```

See Pitto's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914630/python-file-attachment-not-working-while-sending-email-by-crontab).

I'm guessing updating the path variable for cron's environment from crontab itself would be a viable solution as well.